# RE Construction: Strings of even length in alphabet {a,b,c} that contain exactly one a

Tags: regular-expressions

i am reviewing older exams from my computational theories lesson in university and i am struggling to figure this one out: 
Construct a regular expression for the following language: Strings of even length in alphabet {a,b,c} that contain exactly one a.

Roughly translated from greek, hope it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that if a string contains one $a$, then it can be written as $xay$, where $x,y \in (b+c)^*$. Furthermore, $xay$ has even length if either $x$ has even length and $y$ has odd length, or vice versa. Using this, it is straightforward to come up with a regular expression.

Comment: Ah yes, i couldn't figure out how to make sure it had even length. So a solution like this should be right:           ((b+c)(b+c))*a(((b+c)(b+c))*(b+c))*+ (((b+c)(b+c))*(b+c))*a((b+c)(b+c))*

Comment: Your regular expression also accepts $ab^6$, which has odd length. But something very similar would work.

Comment: Right, i shouldn't use Kleene star on the whole odd thing then. So something like this: 
((b+c)(b+c))*a((b+c)(b+c))*(b+c)+ ((b+c)(b+c))*(b+c)a((b+c)(b+c))* . 
Thanks a ton for your help and your time

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is:
(b|c)((b|c)(b|c))*a((b|c)(b|c))* | a(b|c((b|c)(b|c))*)

Logic behind this is:
If you start with a, you need at least one more b|c and then as many b|c PAIRS as you want.
Otherwise you can start with b|c combinations making sure they are an odd number, add the 'a' later to make it even in total and continue with b|c pairs.

Υ.Γ:
Πες μου οτι διαβαζες θεωρια υπολογισμου απο Κατσαρο